# Superposition of two waves

Tags: trigonometry

> Two waves on the string of a musical instrument superposition to give you a
>   third wave. One wave is given by the equation $y =\sin(30t)$ and the other is given by
>   $y = \sin(32t)$. The superposition of the two waves makes a sound (a hum) of a certain
>   frequency, the amplitude of which varies periodically, making beats. What is the frequency
>   of the hum and what is the frequency of the beats that you hear? Assume that time is given
>   in seconds.

I don't know how to approach this computationally, but this is the graph of the superposition function $\sin(30t)+\sin(32t)$.

[image]

My understanding, if correct, is that each individual peak and trough implies finding the frequency of the beats, whereas the periodicity of the "larger" sinusoidal wave represents the frequency of the hum.

How can I approach this computationally? To find the beat frequency, do I set the superposition function equal to $0$ and then solve? For the hum frequency, equal to $1$? Or what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use a trig formula to combine the terms:

$$sinx+siny = 2sin((x+y)/2)cos((x-y)/2)$$

In our case we get:

$2sin(31t)cos(1t) %and the amplitude is between %[-2,2]$

If I'm not mistaken, the beat frequency is given as $f_{beats}=|f_1-f_2|=2$. The cos is responsible for the "beat effect", and is the envelope for the other wave, which is the hum. The frequency is 2*pi*31.

Comment: please use a backward slash when writing trig functions. E.g., use `\sin x` to get $\sin x$. Same with $\cos x$, $\tan x$, arctan, sinh, etc.  `\trigfunction`